# Can't purchase Great Prophet

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

So I just got the message that my automatic purchase of Great Prophet is no longer valid! Checking the religion list of automatic purchases, the Prophet pick is gone, only buildings and missionaries are available. Anyone know why it's so?

Comment: Which era are you in?  Once you hit the Industrial they become available for purchase rather than being generated, so it may be related to that rollover.

Comment: Do you have any cities with your religion as the majority religion? Though I'm not sure that actually affects anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The religion must be the majority in the holy city. I know that sounds redundant, but the AI loves to convert your holy city!

Comment: It seems that the list in the religious overview is a bit wonky. I could still purchase a GP by the city screen eventhough it didn't appear in the automatic purchase.

Comment: @Sandokan In that case, do you get a GP for the other religion?